# Display output in parts in PHP

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i<30; $i++)
{
    echo "$i<br>";          
    usleep(100000); 
}

?>
```

I would like to know how make the browser display 0, then 1, then 2, ...

In my example, it loads for a while and then display 0-29.

Comment: I'm curious. Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disable all output buffering and pad the output:

```
while(@ob_get_clean());

for($i = 0; $i<30; $i++)
{
    echo str_pad("$i<br>",4096);          
    usleep(100000); 
}
```

Also, this won't work, if your Apache is using `mod_deflate` and you have gzip-compression for `text/html` files.

Comment: what is the purpose of str_pad?

Comment: Output isn't sent immediately by Apache. It is sent in chunks of a certain size; hence the padding.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Is there a way to remove mod_deflate and gzip from one single file and make them work the other files?

Comment: Yes. You'll have to activate it locally (not in the `httpd.conf`) by using an `.htaccess` file in a directory in which you'd like compression and put the scripts that aren't to be compressed in a different directory.

Comment: Is there a way to disable gzip & deflate from one directory instead? How can I do this? Can this be done with PHP? If not, .htaccess? Thanks.

Comment: It can be achieved w/ an `.htaccess` file. In a `<FilesMatch>` block, put `RemoveOutputFilter .php`. The output will not be handled by `mod_deflate` then.

Comment: Thanks. To remove gzip, I did this: SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI FILE_NAME\.php$ no-gzip dont-vary   It's working.

Comment: is there any way to replace `str_pad` in order not to affect the page layout (if I want to display as plain text) ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor You mean `Content-Type: text/plain` or "plain" text in `<pre>`? The former, at least, cannot be achieved to my knowledge.

Comment: i'm talking about former one. Oops, how about appending invisible ASCII codes ?

Comment: Try the ["invisible separator"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2063/index.htm) (`\u2063`) and let me know how it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

Flush the output buffer manually:

```
<?php
ob_start();
for($i = 0; $i<30; $i++)
{
    echo "$i<br>";
    ob_flush();
    usleep(100000); 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another perhaps quicker way is to do

```
<?php ob_implicit_flush(true); ?>
```

to tell php to flush the output buffer after each output, not at the end of the file being processed.

Comment: Way to go! Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript. HTML isn't an interactive console.

EDIT: Those of you downvoting, please remember that I am proposing an actual working solution. Incremental output from php is in no way a valid solution here, because there are some many places along the way where it could get buffered, and browsers are in no way obligated to render html incrementally as it comes in.

Comment: He wasn't asking about HTML. This question is about PHP.

Comment: he clearly IS talking about html. See the <br> tag in the output?

Comment: ...and yet, it's still PHP. Think about non-blocking FTP uploads processed by a PHP file. It can be quite interactive then.

Comment: He wants to use PHP but he can't. This is a javascript effect. He needs to use setTimeout(). PHP will render his code and then send all the HTML as once to the client. That's what PHP do in combation with Apache. You can use PHP-CLI, that will work but only in console mode.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience there is no reliable way to make a webpage send output data in realtime.

There are many different places where it can go wrong - and while you can easily get it to work on a single situation there will always be other places where the solution does not work.

Ultimately the only reliable solution is to execute your php code from a shell prompt (via SSH or whatever) and completely bypass apache and web browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression',0);
@ini_set('implicit_flush',1);
@ob_end_clean();
set_time_limit(0);

echo "Yes";
sleep(5);
echo " sir";
```

Don't ask me to explain it, but this works for me.